# What's the proper way to merge two projects in source control software

Tags: fossil

I'm using Fossil-SCM to maintain my projects. Since I don't work in a team I usually have just a very linear branch of development: 1.0 -> 1.1 -> 1.2

I'm wondering what the procedure is when you have one project who's task is about to be given to a related project. And thereby rendering the first project obsolete. Although I tend to rewrite most of my code if I don't remember having already written it, I still would like to keep the code archived. And I'ld rather not have a fossil repo that just is dead. Can I merge it? Is that the proper way of handling this?

For example the code was extracting data from an excel file in order to format an HTML page. Now, I've convinced my employer to move their excel spreadsheet into a database to decrease redundancy, increase efficiency and yaddy yadda. Since I can now make logical queries that don't have to jump hoops to preform using the database I won't need the extra vbs files that originally manipulated the excel file. Technically I would be porting part of the existing code into the current new project.

Since it already has it's own trunk, would it be advisable to combine the trunk of a different project to this one, and how would I do that exactly??

SO I guess my tree would look like this, and I haven't seen examples of software branching that resemble this inverted tree before so I'm wondering what the norm for a situation like this?
[image: It merges at 1.8!!]

Comment: Sound's you are overcomplicating things. What's so bad about a "a fossil repo that just is dead"? Replace "dead" by "archived" and it does not sound so negative any more.

Comment: I have done this before with Mercurial, my advice would be to mark the old project as archived at some point, and copy the resources you need to the new one, because if you don't really need the old-history it's not necessary to merge both projects.

Comment: What keeps you from merging? And even if you merge, the old trunk will still be there. Merging does not remove branches, it just merges files from branch A to branch B.

Comment: I think the what keeps me from merging is that I have two different fossils a.fossil and b.fossil so I'm not sure how I would get all the history and check-ins information to be present in the second fossil. Now that I am much older I think the question is How do you merge two repositories into one.

Answer (score 1):

How best to merge projects depends a bit on how you want to manage their history, and whether you expect them to continue to evolve separately.

#### Keep them separate - use externals/submodules

A very good technique to consider would be that of submodules. Git, and svn have this concept (called externals in svn), but unfortunately, it appears fossil does not (https://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg14798.html).

But the idea is that you can have a project DEPEND on another project, and you just select which branch or tag or individual commit from that other project you want to use in the referencing project.

#### Just copy it

If you just want to lift a bunch of code, and DONT care about the history, you can just add a folder with the new code, and commit it.

#### Just copy but preserve older history

If you want to merge the code from the second project into the first, and preserve history, with git at least, you can use git merge (see https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/ for an example).  git allows targeting other repositories as the source of data to merge from (this is basically how git pulls work). I don't know enough about fossil to know if fossil merge can be used this way.